# Prevent out-of-range error while doing a ariphmetic operation in Mysql strict mode

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
UPDATE enteties SET count=count-7 WHERE id=1
```

`сount` field id enteties table is:

```
`count` mediumint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

If sql strict mode is on and `count` value is less then 7 at the moment when the query is done, an error will be fired:

> BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(enteties.count - 7)'

Is there a way to prevent it in the same query? For example to equate the value to 0 if the result of subsctraction will be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `case`:

```
UPDATE enteties
    SET count = (case when count < 7 then 0 else count-7 end)
    WHERE id = 1;
```